# Unable to load UI components on browser in maven based client server application

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, backbone.js, client-server

[image]
Above pic is the directory structure of my project, containing both client and server side code. Its a maven project, with server in springs and UI in backboneJS

My pom.xml is like below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.adobe.taskprocessor</groupId>
  <artifactId>Asynctaskprocessor</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>Asynctaskprocessor</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <atomikos.version>3.8.0</atomikos.version>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2.RELEASE</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.8</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax</groupId>
      <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
      <version>6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
      <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
      <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
      <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
      <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate4</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Data Mapper package is a high-performance data binding package built
    on Jackson JSON processor -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.3</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson is a high-performance JSON processor (parser, generator) -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.3</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Asynctaskprocessor</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
          <compilerArguments>
            <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
          </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
              <silent>true</silent>
              <artifactItems>
                <artifactItem>
                  <groupId>javax</groupId>
                  <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                  <version>6.0</version>
                  <type>jar</type>
                </artifactItem>
              </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
      <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please
        replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.
      </name>
      <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

This is my index.jsp file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;">
        <title>Enter your first name</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="build/css/master.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test" class="test"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="build/js/main_base.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                ELM.Test.init({
                    el: '#test',
                    visible: true
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And web.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
           <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

And applicationcontext.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
       xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd" >
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.adobe.asynctaskprocessor" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">

        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="atom" value="application/atom+xml"/>
                <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
                <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
            </map>
        </property>

        <property name="viewResolvers">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
                    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />

   <import resource="rabbit-listener-context.xml"/>
   <import resource="mailConfiguration.xml"/>
</beans>
```

I am seperately compiling UI code via grunt and there by build directory gets created in app folder. After that i am doing mvn clean package in current directory, and its creating war file. After deploying the war file on tomcat , when i am accessing my application using http://localhost:8080/Asynctaskprocessor/ , it is not loading the css and js files in       /webapp//app/build folder, so it is not loading the UI components and giging error on loading page , js and css files not found. Any idea, where i am missing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a maven question and backbone has nothing to do with this...

Comment: In your browser's console what do you see... 404?? I guess you should use <mvc:resources mapping="/build/**" location="/build/">

Answer (score 0):

You should update your dispatcher-servlet.xml and add the following line:

```
<mvc:resources location="/app/build/" mapping="/app/build/**" />
```

location and mapping would be your UI component resource location and there mapping url. This would configure spring to allow access to these components.